# Java JUnit test does not pass

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a method that has to return true if the name is matched by the regular expression or null if the name has special characters or numbers.

This is the method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public boolean containsSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$/");
    //check if the name has special characters
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    boolean b = m.find();
    //cast the null to boolean
    Boolean boolean1 = (Boolean) null;
    if (m.matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return boolean1;
    }    
}
```

And this is the test for the method that cannot pass:

```
@Test
public void parseBeanCheck() throws NumberFormatException, IOException, SAXException, IntrospectionException {

    IngenicoForwardingHelper helper = new IngenicoForwardingHelper();

    String test1 = "Steve Jobs";
    Assert.assertTrue(helper.containsSpecialCharacters(test1));
    //This should return Null 
    String test2 = "Steve Jobs1";
    Assert.assertNull(helper.containsSpecialCharacters(test2));
    //This should return Null 
    String test3 = "Steve Jöbs";
    Assert.assertNull(helper.containsSpecialCharacters(test3));
}
```

Comment: and what fails exactly? what is this supposed to do? //cast the null to boolean
                 Boolean boolean1 = (Boolean) null;

Comment: or rather, with return m.matches();

Comment: @JackFlamp I've got a feeling that that test is supposed to fail

Comment: Also why aren't you returning `false` rather than `null` ?

Comment: @Antony it seems very unlikely your method should (be able to) return a null.

Comment: Maybe make your return type `Boolean` instead of `boolean` and for `true` use `Boolean.TRUE`. But I agree with @Berger that why you want to return `null` instead of `false` ?

Comment: since I don't understand the question I just throw out this: if you want your regex to match with white space, remove a \ so it becomes `^[a-zA-Z\s]+$`

Comment: @Jack Flamp. You're right, but it needs to be doubly-escaped when it's inside a String, otherwise it's treated as a character by the tokenizer (and will fail because `\s` is not a valid character).

Comment: @aetheria oh yes forgot about that is was Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method returns a `boolean` which is a primitive type that only allows values `true` and `false`. It does not allow `null`, so your tests that `assertNull()` will never work!

You could change the method signature to return a `Boolean` instead, but it's generally better to avoid returning `null` from methods, if possible. Returning `true` or `false` would make more sense than `true` or `null` anyway.

In Java, your regular expression doesn't need (and shouldn't have) the slashes at the start and end.

You can change your code to something like this:

```
public boolean containsSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z\\s]+$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return !m.matches();
}
```

Or even more simply:

```
public boolean containsSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    return !text.matches("[a-zA-Z\\s]+");
}
```

And the test to something like this:

```
@Test
public void parseBeanCheck() throws NumberFormatException, IOException, SAXException, IntrospectionException {

    IngenicoForwardingHelper helper = new IngenicoForwardingHelper();
    Assert.assertFalse(helper.containsSpecialCharacters("Steve Jobs"));
    Assert.assertTrue(helper.containsSpecialCharacters("Steve Jobs1"));
    Assert.assertTrue(helper.containsSpecialCharacters("Steve Jöbs"));
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that `\s` will match not only spaces, but also tabs, newlines, carriage-returns etc. So make sure that's what you want.

Comment: How can I make this to accept also "-"? this is the pattern  p = Pattern.compile("^([A-Z][a-z]*((\\s)))+[A-Z][a-z]*$");  I would like to accept also: example: Martin Harry-Potter    how this can be added here?

Comment: It's normally expected that you ask a full new question on Stack Overflow than add comments asking new questions. That way the questions are more focused and you'll build up more points too.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score -1):

You should probably simplify your special character check to something like:

```
public boolean containsSpecialCharacters(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return m.find();
}
```

And use `Assert.assertTrue` and `Assert.assertFalse` for your tests